# Wired Connection Failed, Restarts Can Fix

Tags: networking, internet

I've been getting occasional wired connection fails. Rebooting once, twice or more will solve the problem, and when it works it works by the time it hits the login screen (seconds on SSD). I'm running 19.04. I get a similar issue on my laptop (except it is wireless) running 18.10. Both these machines also have windows installs that don't seem to experience this issue so I am nearly certain it is not my router/modem/network (which is new). I would rather restart the network connection / interfaces via terminal if possible, or better yet resolve the issue. I have tried turning on and off the connection in settings and that doesn't work. What are some good troubleshooting steps when this occurs?

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 94:de:80:6c:5b:dd
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:d3a00000-d3a1ffff memory:d3a3d000-d3a3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3800000-d380ffff

/etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: 19.04 is not fully baked, so we really don't discuss it here (until later in the month). However, show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` from both machines. Does the 18.10 laptop also have SSD?

Comment: on 19.04 I get # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager   . Note this is not during an error state, this is while the internet is working fine. Yes both are SSDs.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema happened again so I posted output (taken while down), 3 restarts no good. I booted into windows it worked, then back into ubuntu and it worked again....

Comment: Is this a desktop machine? What make/model? Have you checked for a BIOS update? Is the ethernet card a PCI card? If so, can you re-seat it in its slot. Lets see what happens. Your lshw when it was down looks normal.

Comment: Yes its a desktop. Custom built it in 2014... Ethernet is on the board, good suggestions I'll post back if I make any progress.